# What address do I use to register for information on the GST & HST?

Tags: canada, gst, hst

What address do I use to register for information on the GST & HST?

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what you're asking, but:

(1) If you're interested in learning about **registering** for the GST or HST – for instance, if you run a small business or work as an independent contractor and need to charge the tax – then please check out [Canada Revenue Agency - Registering (opening) your GST/HST account](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/gst-tps/rgstrng/menu-eng.html).

(2) If you're interested instead in more information on the **transition to HST** in Ontario, you'll find some information on the move to HST at:

**Ontario Ministry of Revenue:**

- [Harmonized Sales Tax (HST) and Comprehensive Tax Package](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/index.html).
  This information is a good starting point from the consumer perspective.
- [Single Sales Tax (Harmonized Sales Tax) - Information Notice 1](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/01.html).
  There are also follow-up notices: [2](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/02.html), [3](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/03.html), [4](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/04.html), [5](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/05.html), [6](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/06.html).

**Other:**

- [Canada Revenue Agency - HST for Ontario](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/gncy/hrmnztn/on/menu-eng.html).
- There's also some great information on the HST at [TaxTips.ca - Ontario HST](http://www.taxtips.ca/gst/onhst.htm).

If there's something more specific you're interested to know about the GST or HST, please comment or revise your question to let us know.